# rake db:migrate doesn't work and brings me back to the command line rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake, migrate

Using rails 3.1.1 for windows with railsinstaller

```
>rake db:migrate
```

after a pause, brings me right back to the command line.  No errors, no messages, just right back to the command line.

I tried

```
>rake --trace db:migrate

** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment 
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

Doesn't look like anything is wrong, but obviously something isn't working right.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is the output I would expect if you ran db:migrate in a case where there aren't any new migrations to run.  In fact I just tried it on a local project to be sure, and that's the output I get.  What are you expecting to see here?

Answer (score 2):

If there are no migrations to be run, there will be no output. The `--trace` command outputs the various steps that rake goes through to prepare, execute, and clean up after the migration. However, when it sees that there is no migration to be run, then it doesn't actually make any DB changes. Only DB changes cause additional output.

The only difference between this and a migration is that the changes to the DB will be output to the command line. No changes => no output.

Comment: Thanks - for some reason I thought I had changes to make, but it started working after I added another resource.  How do you get a manually edited migration file to make changes to the database ?

Comment: You have to make sure it follows the proper naming convention, and that's it: a full timestamp value followed by it's name, and ending with `.rb`. You must also make sure that the timestamp value is greater than the current timestamp version in the DB. It's covered in the 'timestamped migrations' section here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html It's often easiest to simply use the rails generator to automatically create a migration file, and you'll avoid these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the right folder (maybe in the right branch, when using git) and make sure that you have created a migration file.

```
rails generate migration MigrationName
```

Edit the generated file as you wish.